# Upgrading from /oldSyntax to /CLR - is .Net 4.0 a minimum requirement?

Tags: c#, c++-cli, clr

In preparation for moving to VS2015 I'm upgrading several solutions with CLR projects using the old (now deprecated) "old syntax" to rather use the "new syntax" (i.e. switch /CLR instead of /oldSyntax).

The C# projects are targeting .Net 3.5 (we were hoping to migrate to a later version as a separate step).

I have completed all the syntax stuff (and have no further errors/warnings in that respect), but on building receive the following error:

> "SomeAssembly.dll", or one of its dependencies, requires a later version of the .NET Framework than the one specified in the project.

The errors are resolved if I update the C# projects to target .Net 4.0.

Is .Net 4.0 a minimum requirement for using the 'new syntax' (/CLR switch)?

I haven't been able to find any reference material mentioning this.

**EDIT:** The C# projects are all library projects.

**EDIT:** Building under VS2008 the error doesn't manifest, but it does when building under VS2015.

Comment: You can only target .NET 4.x in a VS version >= 2010.  If you want to target 3.5 then you *must* use VS2008.  Either by using it explicitly or by using the Toolset option in VS2015.  Otherwise an inevitably side-effect of the plumbing built into the CRT, necessary to get native C++ code properly initialized, targeting .NET 4.  Mixing isn't possible.

Comment: Great, thanks - if you add that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score -1):

I don't find  any where that dot net 4.0 is prerequisites for CLR switch, Just check your web.config accordingly before updating  the C# projects to target .Net 4.0.

Comment: None of our C# projects have that file, should they? We do have app.config - perhaps that's what you're thinking of?

Comment: if its console application their is a Program.cs file, where you can see all the framework information

Comment: They're not console apps - all are library projects.

Comment: ohkk,then above ans is not usefull

Comment: Hans Passant's comment (on my question, above) appears to be correct - I'd accept it as the answer if he added it as one.